# Why is my app crashing after Integrating webview of flutter.Getting Platform exception

Tags: android, exception, flutter, webview, visual-studio-code

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create an already created platform view, view id: 0
    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:85)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
    io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
, null))

Flutter doctor
No issue found. All Good

```
 `import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'rion',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller=
    Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Browser"),),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://google.com",
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Could you provide some more details like the piece of code you wrote and which version of flutter etc?

Comment: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable •

Comment: I added the code, It's a simple one file code. you can check.

Comment: But it's giving a platform exception and also crashing when releasing an apk on real android not emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the `webview_flutter` plugin back in Flutter version 1.12. This has been fixed back in February 2020 as mentioned on this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47935#issuecomment-585052973). Upgrading to the latest Flutter version by running `flutter upgrade` should solve the issue.